Issue with Query Parameter in Nest.js Application
I'm encountering an issue where the limit query parameter in my Nest.js application's GET endpoint is consistently appended with a question mark (20?). This occurs despite correctly formatting the parameter in my Next.js frontend.
Here's my Nest.js controller method:
    @Public()
    @Get()
    findAll(
      @Query('current') currentPage: string,
      @Query('limit') limit: string,
    ) {
      console.log('Received query params:', { currentPage, limit });
      // Further logic to process query parameters
    }


Details
Frontend: I'm using Next.js to construct URLs with query parameters. Here's how I append the limit parameter:

const url = new URL(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/v1/movie);
url.searchParams.append('current', meta.current.toString());
url.searchParams.append('limit', meta.limit.toString());
console.log("Request URL", url.toString());

Backend: In my Nest.js controller, I'm logging the received query parameters and noticing the limit parameter consistently has a question mark appended (20?).
Expected Behavior
The limit parameter should be correctly formatted without any additional characters like the question mark (20 instead of 20?).
I've verified the network request from Next.js to Nest.js using browser developer tools, and the constructed URL appears correct (http://localhost:8000/api/v1/movie?current=4&limit=20).
Testing with Postman does not show the question mark, suggesting the issue might be specific to how Nest.js parses or interprets the query parameter.
What could be causing the limit query parameter in my Nest.js application to consistently have a question mark appended (20?), and how can I resolve this issue?

I hope you are sending query parameters from the postman not the form data you code from nest.js looks fine.
